# Update my application using c#

Tags: c#, updates

I'd like to create an updater that checks if the main .exe file is updated. Must i create an updater file that closes the main application and overwrites the .exe file or is there another way?

Comment: Need more information, what is your design so far?

Comment: you could use ClickOnce, it can handle automatic updates, but has some limitations also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Must i create an updater file that closes the main application and overwrites the .exe file or is there another way?

If you want to overwrite the exe then yes you must exit the currently running exe. The way I currently handle this is the following (it is a Winforms app for the record)

1) update check is performed from internet
2) download of update starts to temporary folder (yourapp/temp_update)
3) once download completes, application uses `Process.Start` to launch updater.exe
4) updater.exe is passed arguments via the command line - namely the exe name and folder location so it can

know which Process to wait for exit (your main application)
where to copy the new exe (and any other files)
eg

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "updater.exe"
process.StartInfo.Arguments = " yourApp.exe temp_update"
process.Start();
//now exit your app.
Environment.Exit(0);  //if Winforms app then just call `.Close()` on your main form
```

4) main application exits
6) updater.exe calls `Process.Start( )` to restart your main application; update.exe then 
5) updater.exe detects exit - it can now copy the new exe over the old one  exists

Rarely, updater.exe itself needs updating -  i embed it inside inside the exe (This is typically ok because update.exe is tiny) - the new exe would then extract it and copy over the existing updater.exe.

I've seen some other possible alternatives using `AppDomain`s whereby your exe is a *very* lightweight executable that checks for updates and then loads your 'main application' into a new AppDomain : (pseudo code)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
      //dont reference MyApp.dll from this exe!
      if(CheckForUpdate())
      {  
         //download new MyApp.dll
      }

     //load MyApp.dll in a new AppDomain
}
```

however the problem with these approaches it doesnt matter how lightweight you make that initial exe you may need to update it and then you are back at the original problem!

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to see an example of the methods that close the application and that start the updater?

Comment: @AsAs have updated answer. are you having a specific issue with that part of your updater?

Answer (score 0):

You must. And it is more complex. Normal users have no right to replace an executable for security reasons. It requires escalated rights as the programs folder is protected.

I would start looking into installer technologies and make a version check before. This is not that hard.

Comment: `It requires escalated rights as the programs folder is protected.` <-- what if you install initially to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local` ?

Comment: And are there problems with Administrator account in Windows?

Comment: @AsAs No user is a Admin, at least if he has more brains than a programmer ;)